# Frez Systems' MD5 code in VB and MSDN's C# MD5 code equivalent?

Tags: c#, vb.net, encryption, md5

On a given system they used an MD5 hash from Frez Systems [Frez Systems](http://www.frez.co.uk/vb6.aspx)

They use this to "encrypt" the password of a user and store it in a database. My task is to write a C# application that needs to verify this same user, but from a different angle. So I need to "encrypt" the password and compare the encrypted password generated from VB in the database, with the encrypted password generated in C#. 
Now, the encrypted password I get from the above mentioned Frez Systems, and the one from  [C# MD5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez5bche8.aspx) do not match. So I'm wondering whether I'm using the correct C# equivalent? Or whether there is something wrong with the Frez Systems version?

Anyone had the same experience?

Comment: Lets make one thing crystal clear A password hashed by MD5 is not encrypted.  MD5 cannot be reversed.  A MD5 hash method will always generate the same MD5 for a giving string.  So unless there is a `salt` involved you will have to provide more information.  The website you linked to is dead, this a closed or open, library?

Comment: The link has a period in it, which is why it appeared to be dead.  I edited OP's question to fix it.

Comment: It looks like the Frez System's MD5 is written in VB6 - which is **NOT** the same thing as VB.NET.

Comment: If you look at the CMD5.cls file in the MD5.zip download from their site, you can see how they're building the MD5 hash.  I don't know if it's wrong or not, but you could try using their logic in C# to see what you get.  Plus, as @Ramhound said, there may be a salt involved, and if you don't know the salt it won't matter what implementation of MD5 you use - you will not get the same result for a given string.

Comment: @Mikrur - I highly encourage you not to use this library. The following statement: "A common use for MD5 is for password encryption as it is one-way in nature, that does not mean that your passwords are not free from a dictionary attack." is made for both their `SHA-256 Digest` and their `MD5 Digest` which of course is 100% false. Neither `SHA-256` or `MD5` hashes can be considered a form of encryption. A `SHA-256` and `MD5` hash cannot be reversed thus it cannot be considered encryption.

Comment: @Mikrur - Amature hour is the only description possible for `Phil Fresle` and Frez Systems Limited`. Please do the world a favor and point out the security risk of using either hashing digest to protect actual user's passwords.

Comment: @Mikrur - Its pretty clear the way they implemented MD5 was incorrect.  You would have to write your own MD5 class to generate the same MD5 hash as this horrible library does.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your comments, corrections and clarifications. I had my doubts when I saw they used code from a non-standard source. 
There is a salt involved, but I could debug the VB6 code, break at the correct position, get the string that would be sent to the MD5 hashing, and pass this as the input for the C# code. However, with no successful comparison. So either there is a problem when I copy the salted string, or there is an error in the Frez system implementation as suggested above.

Comment: Since MD5 has some known weaknesses, it would probably be best to use a different algorithm to hash the passwords in any case. If this change is made in the system, it could just as well be replaced by C# code using some standard libraries.  
Just for interest sake, is there some reliable VB6 MD5 hashing algorithm available somewhere? Would SHA-2 be a better choice than MD5?

Comment: I suddenly began wondering about something. Couldn't the discrepancy perhaps be attributed to the way that VB6 and C# handle bytes? Am I correct in saying that in Vb6, a byte is from 0 to 255, but in C#, a byte is from -127 to 128? If so, then perhaps the salted string that I grab in the middle of the VB6 debugging session, is not in the correct "format" for input into the C# hashing function, and hence the difference in hashing values?